# Is there a good emacs plugin for Python just like ESS for R and slime for Lisp?

Tags: python, emacs, editor

I have tried Ropemacs and Pymacs, but I don't think they are good enough..

I really like the powerful completion in ESS and Slime.

For python, I usually try iPython if I want to try some function experimentally.

Is there such a emacs plugin(tab-completion) for Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [post](http://pedrokroger.com/2010/07/configuring-emacs-as-a-python-ide-2/) has good tips about Emacs as Python "IDE":

> In this post I’ll show how to configure emacs to write Python programs. We want to have not only basics things like syntax highlighting, but also code completion, easy access to Python’s documentation, ability to check for common mistakes, run unit tests, debugging, and a good interactive programming environment.
>
> This setup is based on ipython and python-mode, but it’s also possible to use rope, ropemacs, and the auto complete mode as we can see here. I didn’t have much luck with ropemacs in the past but I’ll try it again in the future.

Comment: There are some useful tips for Emacs and Python in http://python.about.com/b/2007/09/24/emacs-tips-for-python-programmers.htm

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use: https://github.com/gabrielelanaro/emacs-for-python/

Easy to install and almost everything you'll ever need if you want to configure emacs as a Python IDE

Answer (score 1):

[elpy](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy) is the bee's knees! Best solution I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/ ?

Or : http://www.rwdev.eu/articles/emacspyeng